# Return default value from HashMap

Tags: java

I have this example of HashMap:

```
Map<Integer, String> list = new HashMap<>();

list.put(742, "Veterinary Services (0742)");
list.put(743, "Wine producers (0743)");

list.get(744);
```

Is there a way if I try to get a key without available key to return some default value similar to switch case?

Comment: You mean like [`Map.getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)?

Comment: Can you paste official answer please?

Comment: If you don't want to enter a default value with every entry (as would be the case with Map.getOrDefault(..)), you could use an anonymous inner class like this:

    HashMap m = new HashMap(){
           @Override
           public String get(Object k) {
            if(super.get(k)==null) {
                return "default";
            }
            return super.get(k).toString();
           }
    };